# Select Max Number From Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a Code Receipt Number Auto Generate. Here is my code:

```
var conrecipt = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
conrecipt.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COALESCE(MAX(Reciptno),0) from Registration", conrecipt);
int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
conrecipt.Close();
i++;
Label3.Text = Reciptno + i.ToString();
```

It's working fine. But I need to check 3 tables : Registration, Advance and one more table and need to find max from those id's.

How can I do this in Asp.Net C# and MS SQL Server 2012?

Comment: This is a flawed design and is bound to bring you more and more problems, especially in a multi user environment

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you need to do this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stored procedure to implement the ID logic. In the stored proc you could find the IDs from all the relevant tables and calculate the maximum ID. You would then call the stored procedure from the app.

For an even better solution, have a read about entity relationship design. Receipt is an entity that should define receipts including its ID (primary key) in one place. If Receipt Id is used in other tables this is called a foreign key which should be enforced in the database ensuring that every ID referenced in a table already exists in the "master" receipt table.

Comment: Hello Sir Mr. Under Thank you much for give me Idea  its really very helpful for me save my Job thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You could use union for obtain all the reciptno and the select the max

```
 select COALESCE(MAX(Reciptno),0) 
   from (
    Select Reciptno 
    from Registration
    UNION 
    Select Reciptno 
    from Advance
    UNION 
    Select Reciptno  
    from one_more_table
    ) as t
```

AND If you have nvarchar you could use a convert

```
select COALESCE(MAX( convert (int, t.Reciptno)),0) 
   from (
    Select Reciptno 
    from Registration
    UNION 
    Select Reciptno 
    from Advance
    UNION 
    Select Reciptno  
    from one_more_table
    ) as t
```

Comment: Hello Sir Thanks for Reply I Try this But in Table No1 Receipt  No Highest is 02 And in Table No 2 Receipt No is 010 And in Table No 3 Receipt No is 037 so its must be show 037 But its show 09 From Table 2

Comment: @Vikas  .. but  .. ?

Comment: sorry for My English Sir

Comment: Shouldn't this be `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: @Vikas: You're using VarChars for this sequence? Ouch. Btw, did you notice that your approach also fail with a single table :-)

Comment: the union  just removed  the duplicated  values. instead  union all leave all the values ... in your case the union all is unusefull because you select the max value  .... you select just one value

Comment: @scaisEdge: There are no duplicated values according to the OP :-) UNION applies DISTINCT and you never know if the optimizer is smart enough to eliminate this.

Comment: same old Sir Its catch only 9

Comment: @Vikas: Actually your current design is not failing, because there's an automatic typecast due to the `0` in COALESCE. Of course you could fix the UNION by applying this typecast to each Select, but you should simply stop this totally flawed apprach. Now. Immediately.

Comment: Value in Nvarchar Sir

Comment: @Vikas: How can you get multiple rows with `02` and `010` when it's supposed to be a sequence? What kind of characters do you expect for this column besides digits, so why it's defined as NVarChar? Again, stop using this flawed approach.

Comment: @Vikas: Either a built-in `Identity` for each individual table. Or (if those receipt numbers have any meaning across three tables) `CREATE SEQUENCE` (supported in SQL Server 2012+)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir ScaisEdge i really very thank full you give me your valuable time  thankyouuuuu so much

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(M)
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(Value) as M Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(Value) as M Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(Value) as M Table3
) as x
```

And in general it is more correct to use a sequence for all three tables and there will be no problems with the definition of a new value